# Best approximation of a fraction to a given number

Tags: approximation, fractions, continued-fractions

Given a number $q \in \mathbb{R}$. Find two numbers $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m \leq N$ such that $\left|\frac{n}{m} - q\right|$ becomes minimal.

Quick info: I have no idea which subject area is best for this type of task. I just set myself this task because I find it interesting.

I first had the idea to work with the approach ||Ax - b||, but the problem is not linear. I had then looked in a few books and always it was directly about polynomials or functions to which one could build an orthonormal basis. Therefore my question: How do I solve this problem? Can it be solved analytically at all?

---

Okay, I have now looked at the procedure mentioned in the first answers and it is actually quite simple:

Split the number $q_0 = q$:

$$q_0 = ⌊q_0⌋ + \tilde{q}_0,$$

where $\tilde{q}_0 < 1$. Subsequently, we find a $q_1$ with

$$q_1 = \frac{1}{\tilde{q}_0}.$$

Then the procedure repeats. Finally, the algorithm is:

(1) $q_k = ⌊q_k⌋ + \tilde{q}_k$

(2) $q_{k+1} = \frac{1}{\tilde{q}_k}$

The bestapprixmation is then

$$q = ⌊q_0⌋ + \frac{1}{⌊q_1⌋ + \frac{1}{⌊q_2⌋ \,+ \,\ldots}}$$

Example: $3.1415926...$

$$q_0 = 3 + 0.1415926...$$

$$q_1 = \frac{1}{0.1415926...} = 7.0625... = 7 + 0.0625...$$

$$q_2 = \frac{1}{0.0625...} = 15.996... = 15 + 0.996...$$

$$q_3 = \frac{1}{0.996...} = 1.003... = 1 + 0.003...$$

We then find the following approximations:

$$ q = \left\{3, \frac{22}{7}, \frac{333}{106},\frac{335}{113},\ldots \right\} $$

**But what bothers me a lot here are the big denominators. Already the third fraction is over 100. Is there no fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ with $m \leq 100$, which better approximates the number $\pi$ as $\frac{22}{7}$?**

---

Okay, I have now found a better approximation. It holds:

$$\left|\frac{22}{7} - \pi\right| = 0.0012644892$$

$$\left|\frac{311}{99} - \pi\right| = 0.00017851$$

So the algorithm is only partially suitable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do a [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) and truncate it after some terms. For example, this way, you can find the following approximations for $\pi$, by truncating at various places: $\frac{22}{7}$, $\frac{355}{113}$...

**Edit**

If you don't mind testing all the possibilities, you can also simply compute$$\min_{m=1}^N\left|q-\frac{[mq]}m\right|$$
where $[x]$ is the closest integer to $x$. This is an algo in $O(N)$ so it's not too bad either - it's linear in $N$. The solution is $q\sim\frac{[mq]}m$.

Comment: I mean, not only *can* they try continued fractions, they practically have to, as the successive approximations provide by taking more and more terms of the continued fraction approximation are __provably__ the best approximation one can get without making the denominator larger. (Which is well described in the Wikipedia page linked. I typed this up before checking that out, but it doesn't hurt to have this fact noted within math.se, I think.)

Comment: But what bothers me a lot here are the big denominators. Already the third fraction is over 100. Is there no fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ with $m \leq 100$, which better approximates the number $\pi$ as $\frac{22}{7}$?

Comment: Note that the best rational approximations aren’t necessarily just the cutoff continued fractions (although continued fraction ones are better from some definitions). See the Wikipedia article for more details, but you also need to include small deviations of the contued fractions. $179/57$ is the next best one after $22/7$. See https://shreevatsa.net/fraction/best

Comment: @Eric exactly, however the continued fractions are very efficient to converge to a very good approximation.

Comment: @Physics I edited my answer to provide another algorithm, that is linear in $N$. It's a bit brute force but I think it's not too bad, as you seem concerned with the magnitude of the denominator.

Comment: @PC1 This is really practical. Out of interest, I had looked to see if it was possible to approximate the floor function, but unfortunately not (in a easy and useful way). What I find a bit disappointing: It is very numerical. The algorithm for continued fraction is effectively $O(1)$ when considering decimal digits or the denominator. Is there any way to somehow speed up the algrotihmus you listed with $O(N)$ by estimating it? Or can you somehow make it analytic without an algorithm?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Maybe there are some other ideas but this is what I know! All solutions require to have a proper way to carry floating point computations.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question, if $q$ is rational, then it is exactly a ratio of integers. If it’s irrational, then there is some infinite sequence of rational approximations that converge to your number, so there is no one approximation where the difference is minimal.

What you probably want are numbers with small denominator that approximate your number. In particular, an approximation $n/m$ could be considered the best if it’s closer to $q$ than all other rational numbers with denominator at most $m$.

The standard way to accomplish this uses continued fractions. You can cut off the infinite fraction series to get a rational approximation and it’s possible to prove that this procedure gives all the best rational approximation. See Best Rational Approximations here for more details: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

Comment: But what bothers me a lot here are the big denominators. Already the third fraction is over 100. Is there no fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ with $m \leq 100$, which better approximates the number $\pi$ as $\frac{22}{7}$?